# Using same table for When and Then in gherkin scenario

Tags: cucumber, gherkin

I have a scenario where I need to insert some data in the system and after that, I check if that data was inserted correctly. Something like:

Given the user in the insertion screen

When he inserts the products

```
| Code | Name      | Price |
| 001  | Product 1 | 1,00  |
| 002  | Product 2 | 1,50  |
| 003  | Product 3 | 2,00  |
```

Then he checks if the products were inserted correctly

```
| Code | Name      | Price |
| 001  | Product 1 | 1,00  |
| 002  | Product 2 | 1,50  |
| 003  | Product 3 | 2,00  |
```

I use the same table twice to check if it is indeed the same. I'd like to know if there's a way to make it one single table for both when and then.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Scenario Outlines.

```
Scenario Outline: Insert and Verify data blah blah
Given I insert <code>, <name> and <Price> into database
Then I can verify that <code>,<name> and <price> has been inserted 
successfully
Examples:
| Code | Name      | Price |
| 001  | Product 1 | 1,00  |
| 002  | Product 2 | 1,50  |
| 003  | Product 3 | 2,00  |
```

Comment: I can't because I need to insert all the table data once and then check it. Not one per time as Scenario Outline does.

Comment: Then you need to write two scenarios or two stories/features.  I can't think of any reason why validating after all data is entered is any better than validating data AS it's entered, but if that's what your client wants, write two scenarios/stories.  Then bill them for twice the work.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this (using almost the above answer example)

```
Scenario: Insert and Verify data blah blah
Given I insert the following items into some form
  | Code | Name      | Price |
  | 001  | Product 1 | 1,00  |
  | 002  | Product 2 | 1,50  |
  | 003  | Product 3 | 2,00  |
Then the items should appear on the list
```

At the Given step you perform interactions to insert the items and save them in a variable to use later on the Then step to check existance